# imsave() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arr'(matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ive went to most sites and i still didnt understood what is arr in the plt.imsave(matplotlib), can someone please explain me what it is, with an example.

Thank you,

Example of code:
`plt.imsave("logo.png")`

Comment: "Arr" Stands for array, which means the 2d array containing the pixels representing your image. In short it's the image itself

Comment: `arr` is just your image in array format containing all the pixels of the image.

Comment: Note: 
plt.imsave is used to save individual images or NumPy arrays and require 'arr,' : plt.imsave('image.png', array)

while plt.savefig is used to save complete Matplotlib figure:  plt.savefig('figure.png')

Answer (score 0):

Try with `plt.imsave("logo.png", img)`

Where img is your variable

You can see how to use here: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102363/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave

Comment: it says that image is undefined ``name 'img' is not defined``

Comment: You need to put the var name that contains your image, put your code in the question,

Comment: @Ineedhelpon1question_ 
Checkout this for understanding how it works: https://programtalk.com/python-examples/matplotlib.pyplot.imsave/

Comment: ``for i in range(0, nphotos):
        

   
      #what is gonna be in the image
        plt.imshow(plt.imread(randomizer[0]))
        plt.imshow(plt.imread(randomizer[1]))
        #saving
         plt.imsave(f'finalrender/temporaryrender{i + 1}.png',img)
        plt.clf()``

Comment: plt.imsave("logo.png", nphotos[i])

Comment: it doesnt work error: 'int' object is not subscriptable, i believe its because numberofphotos(nphotos) is an int

Comment: Try this if you can see the img with plt.imshow(plt.imread(randomizer[0]))  plt.imsave("logo.png", randomizer[1])

Comment: hey it still doesnt work, it shows return ``umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'minimum' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U71'), dtype('<U71')) -> None``

Comment: img = plt.imread(randomizer[0]), then plt.imsave("logo.png", img), i not check that you are reading that

Answer (score 0):

Know thy matplot!...

`plt.imsave` is used to save individual images or NumPy array, requiring an **'arr'** argument.

```
plt.imsave('image.png', array)
```

`plt.savefig`, on the other hand, is used to save a complete Matplotlib figure.

```
plt.savefig('image.png')
```